# winforms: ListView with works not working ... Or I forget something

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have a list view with some options and grouped. when I click in "Añadir" button, I set the property `listoperation.ShowGroups = true;` but the behavior of the listview it is not correct.

I would like to show the information like in design page:

[image]

My two objectives are first header like in the image and second indent the checkbox to the right.

When I run the project in screen I see:

[image]

What is wrong? in code behind I don't have anything. Only I added the information via properties. Where in the items I set the group.

I am using Windows 7 and Visual Studio 2013 And Framework 4.0

Can you help me please? What do I forget?

Comment: How did you create grouping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to [enable visual-styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.enablevisualstyles(v=vs.110).aspx). This is usually done in the application entry point.

```
static class Program
{

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles(); // <- Here
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the Groups one by one, either in the Designer or in code:

```
 listView1.Groups.Add("FunnyGroup", "Funny");
```

Then you can set the groups for each Items:

```
listView1.Items[0].Group = listView1.Groups["FunnyGroup"];
```

Both action can be done in the Designer as well..

[image]